# Tools similar to Qt4?

Tags: qt4

I am searching for tools similar to Qt4 which can also produce platform-independent applications and which are also open source.

Do you have any examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:
- [WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)
- [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/)
- [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/)
- [Tcl/Tk](http://www.tcl.tk/)

Comment: plus one on wxWidgets and gtkmm